# C++ User login program only reads the first line of file

Tags: c++, file, authentication

```
void abc::loginUser()
{
    abc x;
    fstream file;
    char usr[25];
    string pwd = "",line;
    int ch;
    file.open("user.txt"),ios::in;
    cout << "User Login" << endl;
    cout << "Username: ";
    gets(usr);
    cout << "Password: ";
    file.seekg(0);
    while(ch = getch())
    { 
        if(ch == 13)
        {
            while(file)
            {
                file >> user.username >> user.password;
                if(strcmp(usr,user.username)==0)
                {
                    if(pwd != user.password)
                    {
                        file.close();
                        cout << "\nLogin Failed";
                        getch();
                        system("cls");
                        x.login();
                    }
                    else if(pwd == user.password)
                    {
                        file.close();
                        cout << "\nLogin Successful";
                        getch();
                        system("cls");
                        x.menuUser();
                    }
                }
                else if(strcmp(usr,user.username)!=0)
                {
                    file.close();
                    cout << "\nUser Not Registered";
                    getch();
                    system("cls");
                    x.login();
                }
                else
                {
                    file.close();
                    cout << "\nLogin Failed";
                    getch();
                    system("cls");
                    x.login();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(ch == 8)
        {
            if(pwd.length() > 0)
            {
                cout<<"\b \b";
                pwd.erase(pwd.length()-1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "*";
            pwd += ch;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the program only reads the first line of user.txt file? I can't seem find a way to fix this issue, tried the file.read method but it also doesn't work.

Is there anything that i should change to improve my code?

Can you guys please help me, a beginner here.

(sorry for my bad english, not my main language)

Comment: Now is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger. Using your debugger lets you run your program one line at a time, monitor the values of all variables, as they change, and observe your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. This is a very simple bug, that you should be able to quickly find using your debugger: why your program reads only one line from the file, and then immediately closes it. Good luck, learning how to use your debugger.

Comment: I think the problem is that every path inside the loop calls `file.close()` so the while exit after first run.

Comment: That's fixed it! I thought because the file.close is inside the if condition, it will not run. Thank you!